# Remove whitespace above and below align environmeent

Tags: align, white-space

I want to remove the whitespace cause by the align environment above and below "Beachte:".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            \sigma_{L} & =  \text{Lochleibungsspannung}\\
            \sigma_{LB} & =  \text{Lochleibungsfestigkeit}\\
            \sigma_{L2} & = \text{Lochleibungsgrenze}\\
        \end{align*}
        {\small Beachte:\\
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & = j \cdot j_s \cdot P_S \text{ \hspace{0.5cm} \uline{\textit{\bfseries \footnotesize oder}}}\\
            P_B & = d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \sigma_L\\
        \end{align*}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Could anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the final extra `\\`s and consider increasing the with of your `minipage` so as to accommodate the longest unbreakable word.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            \sigma_{L} & =  \text{Lochleibungsspannung}\\
            \sigma_{LB} & =  \text{Lochleibungsfestigkeit}\\
            \sigma_{L2} & = \text{Lochleibungsgrenze} % <============
        \end{align*}
        {\small Beachte: % <============
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & = j \cdot j_s \cdot P_S \text{ \hspace{0.5cm} \uline{\textit{\bfseries \footnotesize oder}}}\\
            P_B & = d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \sigma_L
        \end{align*}}
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

The `tabstackengine` provides an alternative, and it doesn't add extra padding, unless you want it, since it puts its results in a tight-fitting LaTeX box.  Here, I even added a 2pt vertical buffer around "Beachte".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{1.1\baselineskip}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\linewidth}
        \alignCenterstack{
            \sigma_{L}  =&  \text{Lochleibungsspannung}\\
            \sigma_{LB} =&  \text{Lochleibungsfestigkeit}\\
            \sigma_{L2} =& \text{Lochleibungsgrenze}
        }\\[2pt]
        {\small Beachte:\\[2pt]
        \alignCenterstack{
            P_B  =& j \cdot j_s \cdot P_S \hspace{0.5cm}
               \underline{\text{\textit{\bfseries \footnotesize oder}}}\\
            P_B  =& d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \sigma_L
        }}
    \end{minipage}

\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the `\shortintertext` command from `mathtools` is what you're after?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin = 0.8cm, hmargin = 1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            \sigma_{L} & = \text{Lochleibungsspannung}\\
            \sigma_{LB} & = \text{Lochleibungsfestigkeit}\\
            \sigma_{L2} & = \text{Lochleibungsgrenze}\\
   \shortintertext {\small Beachte:}
            P_B & = j \cdot j_s \cdot P_S \text{ \hspace{0.5cm} \uline{\textit{\bfseries \footnotesize oder}}}\\
            P_B & = d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \sigma_L\\
        \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]